# How to manage Winform Control between 3 forms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an application that has 2 forms. One is designed for admin access only and the other is for user access only. What i'm wanting to do is to check if the user is admin, if so then make the admin form load ONLY, if the user launching the application is not an admin it loads the user form ONLY. When the user gets finished on their form, it exits the application on close.

Do i need a "logic" form that determines which form to load? I'm having the problem of that it shows all the forms on the screen regardless of the users access. How do i give complete control to a winform over the previous or initial winform loaded at the start? There should only be 1 form on the screen at a time.

Comment: Logic progression should be like this...Check user access, Load proper form, make starting form invisible(closed), close application on user form close event.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? If so, show us the code, so that we can assist you.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one form should ever display during the lifetime of the application, you could determine whether the user is admin before you call Application.Run, like so:

```
If userIsAdmin Then
    Application.Run(New frmAdmin())
Else
    Application.Run(New frmMain())
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you uncheck the 'Enable application framework' option for your project, and set your startup object to Sub Main you can create a new module and put the code inside a Sub Main:

```
Module Main
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim userIsAdmin As Boolean
        ' do your check here
        If userIsAdmin Then
            Application.Run(New frmAdmin())
        Else
            Application.Run(New frmMain())
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

See here for further details:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/10/01/enable-the-application-framework-in-vb.aspx